# hyperlink in jsp using the data from DB2 table

Tags: jsp, struts, db2

I need to display an email address - test@testing.com in my page which needs to be stored in DB2 table. Also I need to proved a link when the user click on - Click here. how should i store the data in DB2 sothat it can be displayed correctly ?  I'm getting all the data from this DB2 table in List. I'm doing `<logic:iterate>`. since other data are just plain text. it displays correctly. But email id and tthe link doesnt. please help.

Comment: when i guve <a href=http:www.aaa.com>Clickhere</a> it displayed as it is. didnt give any hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

You must add the attribute escape=false to the tags that print out the text. However, make sure you sanitize that data in input phase, or you will open the door to XSS security vulnerabilities.